# Load 30 million records from oracle table to memory

Tags: java, database, oracle

I have a table in oracle :

```
id (long), img1 (blob),img2 (blob)...img10 (blob), created (date)
```

The table has around 30 million records. (30,000,000)

I want to load these images into a memory like this `HashMap< id, HashMap<Integer,byte[]>>`

The time taken to load 30 million records sequentially is very high. Is there any way to load the data in parellel ?

EDIT: I used this query to retrieve data:

```
SELECT img1,img2,img3,... 
FROM images 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT A.*, ROWNUM RNUM FROM (SELECT ID FROM images) A 
WHERE ROWNUM <=end) WHERE RNUM >=start);
```

Comment: All tables are orable.

Comment: Are you sure you actually want to do that? It doesn't look like a very smart thing to do...

Comment: Why do you want to do this.  Databases are probably quicker than what you can write.

Comment: So you want to load 300 million BLOB values into memory at the same time? How much memory do you have available to allocate to this?

Comment: @fge yes. instead of getting the data from database every time. we planned to have data in memory and do matching in-Memory.

Comment: @JonK yes. we have 132 gig.

Comment: In that case I'd probably break down the task into say, 30 queries retrieving 1 million records each, setting a high fetch size on the `PreparedStatement`s that are retrieving the data. You'd have to run each query in a separate thread as well - and you'll have to decide for yourself what the optimal number of threads is based on the hardware that the database has behind it. Someone else will likely be able to provide a better solution, but that's what sprang to mind.

Comment: Id is long, but is it a Java's long type or an Oracle's long type?.

Comment: @JonK I updated the question, please see the query I used

Comment: @acesargl It's oracle number

Comment: I'd probably start by doing a `SELECT MAX(id) FROM images`, then you can use that number to find your boundaries. From there, you get `SELECT ... FROM images WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ?`. I don't know off-hand if there's a more efficient clause than BETWEEN, but certainly the SQL is simpler, and I think the intent is clearer too.

Comment: The first `HashMap<id,...>` is clear but why a second HashMap (HashMap access time is slow because of the used hash)? Better use an array or a custom Object with img1-10 as fields. Note: Don't forget to initialize the HashMap with the correct size (>30 million).

Comment: What you are going to do with that after you get them into your Java Objects ? are you going to pool them again into another Table ?

Comment: @primitiveType no I want to use them in application

Answer (score 3):

> The time taken to load 30 million records sequentially is very high.
>   Is there any way to load the data in parellel ?

We are talking about gigabytes of data. The bottleneck of this process will most likely be the throughput of your application-database network connection. On 1gbps network the effective transfer you can achieve is about 85-100 mb per second. For, say, 100 gb the transfer should take at least 1000 seconds, which is ~16,7 minutes.

If your interface is used by anything else, your oracle-app transfer will be smaller. If the database if a few routers away, the time will increase because of increased protocol overhead. And as a result of those the time the read takes will be higher.

Answer (score 3):

You must consider IO bottlenecks in this solution, but with that RAM I assume that you have a big host. Also consider that CPU is not the problem here, but network traffic + disk traffic is the key.

Having said that, I assume that you have an insane network and disk bandwidth.

In this solution you must note:

- I use Java long type to read the id Oracle number (if your actual numbers exceed Java long max value then you must use BigInteger)
- HashMap is not thread-safe, so you must use ConcurrentHashMap to wrap the unsafe HashMap while populating it.
- I have use MOD instead rownum to split the table (but it is easy to transform the query to use rownum (your solution) or width_bucket fuction).
- Read the blob in only one step (so image size cannot exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE; if they can be greater, then use a loop or an alternative read method).

To use it you must execute:

```
String url = ...your JDBC url
String user = ...your Oracle user
String pass = ...your password

int num_of_threads;
ParallelReader r = new ParallelReader(url, user, pass);
HashMap< Long, HashMap<Integer, byte[]>> map = r.read(num_of_threads);
```

The code for ParallelReader is:

```
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class ParallelReader {

    private final String url;

    private final String user;

    private final String pass;

    public ParallelReader(String url, String user, String pass) {
        this.url = url;
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public HashMap< Long, HashMap<Integer, byte[]>> read(int numthreads) {
        HashMap<Long, HashMap<Integer, byte[]>> unsafe_map = new HashMap<>();
        ConcurrentHashMap<Long, HashMap<Integer, byte[]>> safe_map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(unsafe_map);

        Worker pool[] = new Worker[numthreads];
        for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++)
            pool[i] = new Worker(i, numthreads, safe_map);

        for (Worker w : pool)
            w.start();

        try {
            for (Worker w : pool)
                w.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ParallelReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return unsafe_map;
    }

    private class Worker extends Thread {

        private final long mod;

        private final long max;

        private final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, HashMap<Integer, byte[]>> safe_map;

        public Worker(long mod, long max, ConcurrentHashMap<Long, HashMap<Integer, byte[]>> safe_map) {
            this.mod = mod;
            this.max = max;
            this.safe_map = safe_map;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass)) {
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9, img10, id "
                        + "FROM images "
                        + "WHERE MOD(id, ?) = ?");
                pstmt.setLong(1, max);
                pstmt.setLong(2, mod);
                ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
                while (rset.next()) {
                    long id = rset.getLong(11);
                    HashMap<Integer, byte[]> imgs = new HashMap<>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        Blob b = rset.getBlob(i);
                        byte bytes[] = b.getBytes((long) 1, (int) b.length());
                        imgs.put(i, bytes);
                    }
                    safe_map.put(id, imgs);
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ParallelReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no point reading the data on many different connections if they use the same network interface or the same database instance, or even the same network device an the way (unless it's much faster than the link). Either way it's the network that is going to be saturated.

Comment: @Dariusz We cannot assume this. Jhon said he has 132 G RAM, so I assume he does not have a small host. As far as I know,  2014 best network single link was operating at 255 Terabits/second. And it is easy to multiplex ethernet links to increase bandwidth. On the other hand, we don't know anything about Jhon's Oracle architecture (may be Jhon has a single instance or maybe has has a grid system - in this case it is not the same work with one connection than work with many connections).

Answer (score 2):

You could query the DB in parallel slicing the table but you should lock the hashmap when you would write the records. I don't think that you would be faster than reading the table in batches. 
For my experience the bottleneck is the memory allocation: allocate 30M objects in memory is a huge work for your system.
Whatever you want to do with 30M records in memory, try to do it in the DB: they are made to manage that amount of data and optimized for it

Comment: The performance of it is very good....and we are very happy with the results which cannot be achieved reading from database....
there are very huge number of transactions coming in and this can be handle very efficiently if the data is in-Memory rather than reading it from database

Comment: Then before to go further try to calculate the network upper limit and the CPU upper limit: 
calculate the amount of data and what's the minimum time to transfer all the images from the DB to the client. 
Then try to create the same amount of empty images and load the hashmap with dummy values. 
The higher value will be your limit. You couldn't go beyond that. Compare to your current time and check if it's worth to spend more time optimizing your procedure or you must live with that cost